# When entering running app from notification, how to finish current activity

Tags: android

In my app, I have an `Activity` that I only allow one instance of and I `finish` it if the user leaves.  Right now, if the user presses back button or uses navigation drawer to try and navigate elsewhere, I finish that activity or ask them to save changes and then finish it.

I'm implementing a push notification that would allow the user to enter the app and open that activity to the record indicated in the push notification data.  But if the app is already running and user already has that activity open, how can I ask user to save changes or finish the activity before opening the new instance?  Am I thinking about this correctly?

Edit: here is the PendingIntent I am creating from my BroadcastReceiver.

```
private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(String type, String number)
{
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);

    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
    homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(homeIntent);

    Intent queueIntent = new Intent(mContext, QueueActivity.class);
    queueIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    queueIntent.putExtra(QueueActivity.TYPE, type);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(queueIntent);

    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra(DetailActivity.DETAIL_NUMBER, number);
    detailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(detailIntent);

    return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) to the `Intent` that will open the `Activity` from the `Notification`.

Then you can check the [Activity.onNewIntent(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) method to do what you need to do.

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Notification will "enter" your activity through the `onNewIntent()` method. So simply make a condition there, checking if the intent comes from the notification and then react accordingly :-)

Comment: This seems like the right solution but I'm launching the activity as part of a stack.  The FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag seems to be doing nothing because it's launching a new task stack.  I have the root of the stack set to FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT which also isn't doing anything.

Comment: I updated question with the task stack I'm building.